# Why people says 'tho' at the end of the sentence?

Tags: informal-language

I heard many of them used the word 'tho' in their sentence and I'm still can't figure out what it really means and how to use it!

Comment: It's hardly a duplicate when (a)  the OP (or any learner)  doesn't know that *tho* is an alternate spelling of *though* and (b) *tho* does not occur once in the question this is supposed to be a duplicate of.

Comment: Have you looked up *tho* in a dictionary? For instance, [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/tho)?

Comment: @AlanCarmack It's a duplicate when the answer of the duplicate master answers the question. It doesn't matter whether a learner knows what it is. A dictionary or two or [simple Googling](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=J7s9V8qANOjO8geX_ZLoAw#q=define+tho) would have answered this question.

Answer (score 5):

It is short or "textspeak" for *though*.

At the end of a sentence, *though* means:

- Conditions were wrong to do something, or there is a good reason something should not be done.
- That something was done anyway.

> I went to the party, though. (There's a good reason you should not have gone to the party, but you ignored that and went anyway)

Answer (score 4):

**tho(ugh)**

When **though** is the last word in the sentence, it is a marker that the speaker has just added and may be adding some new information which qualifies or limits what he said a second ago, so the listener does not get the wrong idea.

> He knows how to fix cars. He has no formal training, *though*. He
>   learned by watching YouTube videos. Maybe you should take your car
>   to a certified mechanic.
>
> This is the hotel swimming pool. You can't swim in it, *though*.  The
>   filter is broken, and the bacteria level is too high.