# Clarification for the usage of "though"

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, spoken-english, informal-language

I'm only asking for "though" as an adverb. There were already asked questions about this :

[Why people says 'tho' at the end of the sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90406/why-people-says-tho-at-the-end-of-the-sentence)

[Could you clarify when to use "Though" at the end of a sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74934/could-you-clarify-when-to-use-though-at-the-end-of-a-sentence)

but I'm not convinced by the description people gave.

In fact, I sometimes hear **though** in situations where there is no contradiction or opposition... likes in memes or in this video :

https://youtu.be/HVk7koqlu1U?t=62

Can you please tell me the meaning of though in such context ?

Thank you and sorry if what has been written in other questions implies an answer for my question, it's just that for now, I'm not convinced...

Comment: Can you transcribe the video and add it to the question?

Comment: Well he just says "that s a cute name tho" if i m not mishearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, people don't go through all of the rules they would if they were writing when they speak aloud, especially in a situation where they're probably nervous like the one you gave. For those who didn't click on the video, it's one about speed dating 10 guys. Here's a short transcript of the part in question, the whole thing happens in 10 seconds.

> Man: Uhm... Hi?
>   Woman: Hello! Uhm... (both laugh) What's your name?
>   M: I'm Miguel, what's yours?
>   W: I'm Alexa, nice to meet you.
>   M: Nice to meet you. That's a really cute name, though.

Here, keep in mind that the people are a little nervous, even awkward. In spoken (but *not* in written) English, *though* is used not only to contradict another idea but also sometimes just to add an idea. It could also be used as a filler word (like *uh* or *uhm*) to help the conversation along. Just don't dwell on it too much, as it sounds perfectly natural and less awkward if you don't use the *though*. It is by no means necessary.